# get index for every 10 items

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get an index for every 10 item in array. What I did is using modulo but this is not the result I am after. What his give me is

What I want is get O for items 0-9 get 1 for items 10-9.

What I have is a ctr when I increment for every loop. I gave a simple sample using JS but I am doing this in PHP. My code something like this:

```
$ctr = 0;
$listjson=Array ( [0] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [1] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [2] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [3] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [4] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [5] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [6] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [7] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [8] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [9] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [10] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [11] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [12] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [13] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [14] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [15] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [16] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [17] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [18] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [19] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [20] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [21] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [22] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [23] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [24] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [25] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [26] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [27] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [28] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [29] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [30] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [31] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [32] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [33] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [34] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [35] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [36] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [37] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [38] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [39] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [40] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [41] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [42] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [43] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [44] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [45] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [46] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [47] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [48] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [49] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [50] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [51] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [52] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [53] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [54] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [55] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [56] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [57] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [58] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [59] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [60] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [61] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [62] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [63] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [64] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [65] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [66] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [67] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [68] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [69] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [70] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [71] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [72] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [73] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [74] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [75] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [76] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [77] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [78] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [79] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [80] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [81] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [82] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [83] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [84] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [85] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [86] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [87] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [88] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [89] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [90] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [91] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [92] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [93] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [94] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [95] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [96] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [97] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [98] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [99] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [100] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [101] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [102] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [103] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [104] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [105] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [106] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [107] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [108] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [109] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [110] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [111] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [112] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [113] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [114] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [115] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [116] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [117] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [118] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [119] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [120] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [121] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [122] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [123] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [124] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [125] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [126] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [127] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [128] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [129] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [130] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [131] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [132] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [133] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [134] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [135] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [136] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [137] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [138] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [139] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [140] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [141] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [142] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [143] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [144] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [145] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [146] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [147] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [148] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [149] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [150] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [151] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [152] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [153] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [154] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [155] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [156] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [157] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [158] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [159] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [160] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [161] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [162] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [163] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [164] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [165] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [166] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [167] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [168] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [169] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [170] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [171] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [172] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [173] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [174] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [175] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [176] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [177] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [178] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [179] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [180] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [181] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [182] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [183] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [184] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [185] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [186] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [187] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [188] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [189] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [190] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [191] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [192] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [193] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [194] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [195] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [196] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [197] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [198] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [199] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [200] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [201] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [202] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [203] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [204] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [205] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [206] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [207] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [208] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [209] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [210] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [211] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [212] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [213] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [214] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [215] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [216] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [217] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [218] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [219] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) [220] => Array ( [sys_id] => 13 ) ) 

$arrayinjssample= Array ( [0] => 2958 [1] => 2960 [2] => 2960 [3] => 2960 [4] => 2960 [5] => 2960 [6] => 2960 [7] => 2960 [8] => 2960 [9] => 2960 [10] => 2960 [11] => 2141 [12] => 2030 [13] => 2030 [14] => 2030 [15] => 2030 [16] => 1656 [17] => 1060 [18] => 1060 [19] => 1060 [20] => 1060 [21] => 1060 [22] => 60 )

foreach ($listjson as $key => $value) {
    $arrayinjssample[$ctr % 9]
    $ctr++;
}
```

What I have above is I have a listjson with items and for every 10 items in that array I will get the index from the sample in JS. Example is after every 10 Items in my listjson I need to get the index value on the array in js sample below.

Basically What I need to get is a continuous index number. Not returning to 0 like in the result I get above.

UPDATE:

> I want to get index of every 10 items from $listjson on $arrayinjssample.

Example :

```
items 0 - 9 in listjson I want to get index 0 in arrayinjssample 
items 10 - 19 in listjson I want to get index 1 in arrayinjssample 
items 20 - 29 in listjson I want to get index 2 in arrayinjssample
```

and so on

Comment: array_chunk would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PHP7 you can use [intdiv](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.intdiv.php) function:

```
foreach ($listjson as $key => $value) {
    $arrayinjssample[intdiv($key, 10)]
}
```

Or you can make this function yourself:

```
function intdiv_1($a, $b){
    return ($a - $a % $b) / $b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you simply step thought by jumps of 10:

```
for (let i = 0; i > data.length; i +=10) {
    console.log(i)
}
```

prints:
 0
 10
 20

Edit: to get 0, 1, 2, etc you can just dived by 10:

```
for (let i = 0; i > data.length; i +=10) {
    console.log(i/10)
}
```

prints:
 0
 1
 2

Comment: I think you can just divide by 10 if I understand you correctly...see edit.

Answer (score 0):

To get every tenth item in the array you simply increment the counter variable by ten in the loop.

```js
let data = [2958,2960,2960,2960,2960,2960,2960,2960,2960,2960,2960,2141,2030,2030,2030,2030,1656,1060,1060,1060,1060,1060,60]




for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=10) {
  //i is the index of the 10 element in the data variable
  console.log(data[i]);
}
```

Comment: i have question because index starts with 0 what i need is 0 - 9 items get 0 10 - 19 items get 1 20 - 29 get 2.. This is how i see please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: yes.. sorry if i cant explain properly. the scenario is like this.. I have a arraylist and i jave an array also. I want to get a value from array every 10 items in arraylist. I want to get the value based on index of every 10 items

Comment: @Martin Do you want to put the first ten elements of the listjson  array into the first element of the arrayinjssample array?